# Is CloudKit missing from Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to develop an app that will run on both OSX and iOS, using CloudKit to help sync the data.

I've found [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/CloudKit/) for CloudKit on iOS, but I've been unable to find corresponding documentation for OSX.  I'm hoping to use the native SDK's for CloudKit on OSX in C#.  I'm usually pretty good at googling, but I've been unsuccessful thusfar.  Does anyone know definitively if there is a C# API for CloudKit on OSX?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudKit framework for `Xamarin.Mac` is in same namespace as `Xamarin.iOS`: `CloudKit`. Yes, it is available within Xamarin.Mac.

It has the same API between macOS, iOS, tvOS, and watchOS and thus using CKRecord, NSOperation, etc... is a same on the different platforms.

Re: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit?language=objc

**Note:** If you end up needing ObjC/Swift `@dynamic` properties, which are not supported directly via Xamarin, review my bugzilla comments w/ Rolf Bjarne Kvinge and how I implemented them with Core Animation as I've had to use this same method across CloudKit and CoreData frameworks as dynamic-based properties are a hard requirement in some cases...

- https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=38823